# Expo error: EMFILE, too many files open, error in windows while running expo build:android

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting this Expo error:
[image: expo error]

I tried to upgrade node versions, clear cache and temp files from system, nothing worked.

Comment: try downgrading you node version, i saw that this helped some other people aswell

Comment: Any particular version to which i have downgrade??

Comment: not really something i can help you with, most people downgraded from 12.0.4 to v8.11.3 , but you can play around with it a bit

Comment: Nothing works to be honest

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue on SDK version 46.0.0. I solved it by changing the SDK to version 47.0.0